# How MFi communication works?

Tags: ios, mfi

I found in Accessory Interface Specification information about Accessory Authentication and Accessory Identification. My question is - Authentication phase is only once action? For example:
First device connection:

1. Authentication
2. Identification
3. Other

Next device connection:

1. Identification (Authentication phase will be omitted, because at first time device was marked as trusted)
2. Other

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication phase runs every time when device connected.